# Android Studio supports only one settings.gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
- my-base
- my-main
- my-Android
```

`my-main` uses `my-base` and `my-Android` uses my `my-main`.

Here are the `build.gradle` files.

**my-base build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

jar {
  from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
  description "Create source jar."
  classifier = 'sources'
  from(sourceSets.main.allSource) {
    exclude '**/*processor*'
  }
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
  description "Create javadocs."
  classifier = 'javadoc'
  from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
  archives sourcesJar
}
```

**my-main build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'apt'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

eclipse {
  classpath {
     downloadSources=true
     downloadJavadoc=true
  }
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.jimdo.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.5-SNAPSHOT'
  }
}


repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    name = "sonatype"
    url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  }
  maven {
    name = "sonatypeGoogle"
    url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/"
  }
  flatDir {
    dirs 'lib'
  }
}

sourceSets {
  apt{
    java{
      srcDir 'build/source/apt'
      srcDir 'build/source/base'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
  apt (project(':my-base'))
  apt 'com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta2'
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.0-beta'
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'

  compile (project(':my-base'))   

  compile 'com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2' 
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
}

jar {
  from "build/source/apt"
  exclude '**/*.zip'
}
```

**my-main settings.gradle**:

```
include ':my-base'
project(':my-base').projectDir = new File('/absoltePathTo/my-base')
```

**my-Android build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    maven {
        name = "sonatypeGoogle"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.mytest.mytest_android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    compile (project(':my-main'))
}
```

**my-Android settings.gradle**:

```
include ':app'
include ":my-base"
project(':my-base').projectDir = new File('/absoltePathTo/my-base')
include ":my-main"
project(':my-main').projectDir = new File('/absoltePathTo/my-main')
```

In my main Activity I included classes defined in `my-base` and `my-main`:

[image]

When I do `gradle build` from the command line outside of Android Studio I get no errors. When I do `gradle build` in Android Studio I get:

```
Failed to set up dependencies
Error:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':my-main'.
```

**Note:** The problem seems to come from the fact that I have two settings.gradle. One in my.Android and one in my-main.

**How can I get classes from dependent project `my-main` correctly resolved in Android Studio imports? How do I remove the error above?**

Answer (score 0):

In "my-Android build.gradle" under dependencies, you have 
compile (project(':my-main'))

What I infer from your error message is that it's having trouble knowing where ':my-mine' is. Try using the absolute dir to the project and see if that works. If it does, then you know that ':my-main' is not the correct file path.

Comment: I did this in think the problem is having two settings.gradle files.